# "Segmentation fault", x86_64 assembly, AT&T syntax

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I am running my code in a 64-bit Linux environment where the Linux Kernel is built with *IA32_EMULATION* and *X86_X32* **disabled**.

In the book [*Programming from the Ground Up*](http://security.di.unimi.it/sicurezza1314/papers/Assemblerprogramming.pdf) the very first program doesn't do anything except produce a segfault:

```
.section .data

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx

int $0x80
```

I convert the code to use x86-64 instructions but it also segfaults:

```
.section .data

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movq $1, %rax
movq $0, %rbx

int $0x80
```

I assembled both these programs like this:

```
as exit.s -o exit.o
ld exit.o -o exit
```

Running `./exit` gives `Segmentation fault` for both. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have seen a lot of tutorials assembling code with **gcc**, however I'd like to use **gas**.

### Update

Combining comments and the answer, here's the final version of the code:

```
.section .data
.section .text

.globl _start
_start:

movq $60, %rax
xor  %rbx, %rbx

syscall
```

Comment: Does the `int 0x80` still exist in x86_64 ? I thought it has been replaced with `syscall` instruction

Comment: @Pierre replacing `int 0x80` with `syscall` gives me `Segmentation fault`, too.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I use custom kernels and disable i386 emulation, as I never run 32-bit binaries.

Comment: That is the reason you are segfaulting. Most distros turn on IA32 emulation. If you turn it off you can't use `int 0x80` in 64-bit code. You'll need to use the 64-bit `syscall` instruction and convention. A good starting point for that is http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64 .If you turn on IA32 emulation your kernel can use`int 0x80` in 64-bit code, but is limited to 32 bit operands and 32-bit pointers. The upper 32-bits aren't used with IA32 emulation. One downside is stack based pointers can't be passed to `int 0x80`

Comment: When writing x86-64 code `syscall` instruction is preferred. The calling convention and numbering is different than `int 0x80`

Comment: `mov $1, %rax` does *exactly* the same thing as `mov $1, %eax`, except that it takes more bytes of machine code to encode `mov r/m64, sign-extended-imm32`.

Comment: Using `gcc -nostartfiles` to link your executable is just another way to run `as` and `ld`.  Use `gcc -v` to see what it does.

Comment: Run `strace ./a.out` to log the system calls being made.  This won't change the behaviour of either snippet.  Without IA32 support, you'll probably just see a segfault with no system calls.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I ran it before posting, right after the first time I saw it. Both `IA32_EMULATION` and `X86_X32` are not set.

Comment: Better: `mov $60, %eax` / `xor %ebx,%ebx` / `syscall`.  Compare the machine code (`objdump -d`) to see why: same effect with fewer bytes.

Comment: But I'm asking if it segfaulted. Your question suggests the first code snippet you gave us actually exited (that sounds like you were saying it didn't segfault). I'm actually asking this to ensure your question actually was saying what you actually observe with the code snippets you gave. If you have IA32 emulation off, BOTH your code snippets should have failed with a segfault right on `int 0x80`. As it stands your question says the firts code snippet exited, and the second segfaulted. I don't believe that is accurate if you in fact IA32 emulation off.

Comment: @MichaelPetch it did segfault.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you. It clarifies the question.

Answer (score 2):

`int $0x80` is the 32bit ABI.  On normal kernels (compiled with IA32 emulation), it's available in 64bit processes, but you shouldn't use it because it only supports 32bit pointers, and some structs have a different layout.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for info on making 64bit Linux system calls.    (Also ZX485's answer on this question).  There are many differences, including the fact that the `syscall` instruction clobbers `%rcx` and `%r11`, unlike the `int $0x80` ABI.

In a kernel without IA32 emulation, like yours, running `int $0x80` is probably the same as running any other invalid software interrupt, like `int $0x79`.  Single-stepping that instruction in gdb (on my 64bit 4.2 kernel that does include IA32 emulation) results in a segfault on that instruction.

It doesn't return and keep executing garbage bytes as instructions (which would also result in a SIGSEGV or SIGILL), or keep executing until it jumped to (or reached normally) an unmapped page.  If it did, that would be the mechanism for segfaulting.

You can run a process under `strace`, e.g. `strace /bin/true --version` to make sure it's making the system calls you thought it would.  You can also use `gdb` to see where a program segfaults.  **Using a debugger is essential**, moreso than in most languages, because the failure mode in asm is usually just a segfault.

Comment: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) is a more complete canonical version of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first observation is that the code in both your examples effectively do the same thing, but are encoded differently. The site [x86-64.org](http://www.x86-64.org/) has some good information for those starting out with x86-64 development. The first code snippet that uses 32-bit registers is equivalent to the second because of [*Implicit Zero Extend*](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html):

> Implicit zero extend
>
> Results of 32-bit operations are implicitly zero extended to 64-bit values. This differs from 16 and 8 bit operations, that don't affect the upper part of registers. This can be used for code size optimisations in some cases, such as:
>
> ```
> movl $1, %eax                 # one byte shorter movq $1, %rax
> xorq %rax, %rax       # three byte equivalent of mov $0,%rax
> andl $5, %eax         # equivalent for andq $5, %eax
> ```

---

The question is, why does this code segfault? If you had run this code on a typical x86-64 Linux distro your code may have exited as expected without generating a `segfault`. The reason that your code is failing is because you are using a custom kernel with IA32 emulation off.

IA32 emulation in the Linux kernel does allow you to use the 32-bit `int 0x80` interrupt to make calls using the traditional [32-bit system call mechanism](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html).  This is an emulation layer, and doesn't support passing pointers that can't be represented in a 32-bit register. This is the case for stack based pointers since they fall outside the 4gb address space, and can't be accessed with 32-bit pointers.

Your system has IA32 emulation off, and because of that `int 0x80` doesn't exist for backwards compatibility. The result is that the `int 0x80` interrupt will throw a segmentation fault and your application will fail.

In x86-64 code it is preferred that you use the `syscall` instruction to make system calls to the 64-bit Linux kernel. This mechanism supports 64-bit operands and pointers where necessary. Ryan Chapman's site has some good information on the [64-bit *SYSCALL*](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) interface which differs considerably from the 32-bit `int 0x80` mechanism.

Your code could have been written this way to work in a 64-bit environment without IA32 emulation:

```
.section .text

.globl _start
_start:

mov  $60, %eax
xor  %ebx, %ebx
syscall
```

Other useful information on doing 64-bit development can be found in the [64-bit System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). This document also better describes the general `syscall` convention used by the Linux kernel including side effects in *Section A.2* . This document is also very informative if you also wish to interface with third party libraries and modules (like the *C* library etc).

Comment: That's funny, the example on x86-64.org has the byte savings mis-counted.  `gas` assembles `48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax` (7B), using the `REX mov r/m64, imm32(sign-extended)` form.  And `b8 01 00 00 00      mov    $0x1,%eax` (5B), using the `mov r32, imm32` form that encodes the dest reg into the opcode, instead of a mod/rm byte.  (The REX form of that is `movabs r64, imm64`, which is why the `mov r64, imm32` has to use the `r/m64` encoding.)  Nice answer though.  Mine just explained exactly why it faulted, not what to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the [Linux System Call Table for x86_64](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) is different from the table for x86.

In x86, SYS_EXIT is `1`. In x64, SYS_EXIT is `60` and `1` is the value for SYS_WRITE, which, if called, expects a `const char *buf` in %RSI. If that buffer pointer is invalid, it probably segfaults.

```
%rax    System call   %rdi              %rsi            %rdx      %r10  %r8 %r9
1       sys_write     unsigned int fd   const char *buf size_t 
60      sys_exit      int error_code
```

Comment: This is true. However if a kernel is built with IA32 emulation (most are unless you build a custom one turning it off), `int 0x80` is emulated. `int 0x80` in 64-bit code is limited to using only 32-bit operands (obviously) but still matches the IA32 `int 0x80` convention. I queried the OP in the comments and he confirms he turned off IA32 emulation. Had he turned it on this code would have worked. Of course `syscall` is the preferred method in 64-bit code as you can pass 64-bit pointers and other 64-bit operands. In his case the segault is because `int 0x80` is not emulated by his kernel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The result code is `movq $60, %rax` instead of `movq $1, %rax` and `syscall` instead of `int $0x80`.

Comment: Note that `write(2)` returns `-EFAULT` if you pass it a bad pointer.  @Cág: This is why you should use `strace` to see what your program does.  Probably your system call returns, and then execution continues beyond the `int $0x80`, and the data there, when decoded as x86 instructions, causes a segfault.  Or execution continues until instruction fetch itself causes a segfault.  This answer is useful but doesn't explain the observed behaviour at all, because the 32bit `int $0x80` ABI is still accessible from 64bit processes, as Michael points out.

Comment: @PeterCordes : You have missed something. In this case the OPs code doesn't work because his kernel was built as a custom kernel with IA32 emulation off. His code is failing because `int 0x80` isn't supported at all in his environment. My first comments to his question queried whether he happened to build a custom kernel with IA32 emulation off, and that is the case.This question is a dupe of another, I just can't find it. Recently someone else ran a custom kernel with IA32 off and had same issue. He has no choice but to use `syscall` or rebuild his kernel with IA32 emulation on.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yeah, I remember that question.  And no, I didn't miss that, I just didn't find a good way to say everything I meant.  But obviously the only way for the kernel to return from `int $0x80` / `eax=1` is if IA32 support is not present.  (Or maybe the `int $0x80` itself segfaults directly in that case, IDK).

Comment: @MichaelPetch `syscall` though was not the only error in the original code; I used `sys_write` instead of `sys_exit`.

Comment: @Cág : Your code shown in your question doesn't use `syscall` instruction, It uses `int 0x80` which is a different mechanism. There is a part of me that believes if you took the first example code you posted here as is and built it (and ran it), and you have IA32 emulation off, it should segfault (not exit gracefully). The 2 examples you posted in your question should have both failed (I'm pretty sure) in an environment with IA32 emulation off.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. @Peter Cordes: You may be right about `-EFAULT`, but from my experience programming linux assembly, I (nearly?) always get a segfault returned on command line. Maybe the output lacks differentiation, I never investigated that. If the `int 0x80` just IRETs and continues afterwards to nowhere or if it's an issue with the IDT, IDK either.

Comment: @zx485: most SO questions where people screw this up segfault because execution continues after something they expected to exit, not because `write(2)` itself faults.  I'm 100% sure about this, having tested myself single-stepping in GDB.  System call man pages always document returning `-EFAULT` for bad pointers, not actually raising a `SIGSEGV`.  AFAIK the only system call that can directly generate a `SIGSEGV` is `kill(self, SIGSEGV)` :P

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'm *sure* it would not exit gracefully.  Assuming that disabling IA-32 support doesn't leave any kind of vestigial handler, the IDT entry for `0x80` with is probably the same as the entry for e.g. `int $0x79`.  In a 64bit process on my normal 4.2 kernel, single stepping `int $0x79` in gdb generates a SIGSEGV.  If it does return at all, then it would just continue on into bogus instructions.